# Определение сканера в МФУ

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня есть MФУ Canon PIXMA MG2440 и PC с Ubuntu Desktop 14.04(x32).
При подключении МФУ появляется устройство `/dev/usb/lp0`.
lsusb видит его как:
`Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04a9:176c Canon, Inc.`

При попытке сканирования в стандартной программе ubuntu, он пишет что сканер не подключен, тоже самое происходит с:

- sane-find-scanner
- Vuescan
- Sane

Поставил программу с официального сайта [ScanGear MP](http://www.canon.ru/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/mg2440.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:203-1093735&os=Linux%20(32-bit)&language=), запустил её ,и о чудо она работает. Но она работает в графической оболочке.

Мне нужно что бы я мог сканировать из консоли (или скриптом).
Я так понимаю что все программы ищут в `/dev/usb/` что-то типо `scanner0`, но там только `lp0`, я так понимаю так называются принтера, а не сканеры.

Как можно отсканировать из терминала?

Comment: вам следует обратиться к производителю сканера.

Comment: @alexander barakin, а что они сделают? Они же не будут ради меня писать программу, а что они скажут пользоваться сторонней программой, что-то не верится.

Comment: вряд ли посещающие этот сайт программисты справятся с написанием драйвера лучше производителя этой неведомой железки.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он фактически сводится к просьбе найти некую программу (скорее всего, вообще не существующую)

Comment: Ладно, сейчас напишу и производителю.

Comment: @alexander barakin, не факт, возможно можно настроить в ОС так что бы оно(МФУ) определялось, не как принтер, а как сканер.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать симлинк scanner0 на lp0. Да и вообще подобные вопросы лучше на других ресурсах задавать, тут посетители не нужны.

Comment: @dsnk, на счёт симлинка, попробую. А не подскажите на каких ресурсах лучше это делать, я таких лично не знаю.